# Java Generics E extends Comparable<E> leaves warning

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to make a Generic class where `E extends Comparable E` but I get a warning in Eclipse that says:

> LinkedList.Node is a raw type. References to generic type LinkedList E .Node E  should be parameterized

Here is the code:

```
public class LinkedList<E extends Comparable<E>>



{
    // reference to the head node.
    private Node head;
    private int listCount;

    // LinkedList constructor
 public void add(E data)
    // post: appends the specified element to the end of this list.
    {
        Node temp = new Node(data);
        Node current = head;
        // starting at the head node, crawl to the end of the list
        while(current.getNext() != null)
        {
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        // the last node's "next" reference set to our new node
        current.setNext(temp);
        listCount++;// increment the number of elements variable
    }
 private class Node<E extends Comparable<E>>
    {
        // reference to the next node in the chain,
        Node next;
        // data carried by this node.
        // could be of any type you need.
        E data;


        // Node constructor
        public Node(E _data)
        {
            next = null;
            data = _data;
        }

        // another Node constructor if we want to
        // specify the node to point to.
        public Node(E _data, Node _next)
        {
            next = _next;
            data = _data;
        }

        // these methods should be self-explanatory
        public E getData()
        {
            return data;
        }

        public void setData(E _data)
        {
            data = _data;
        }

        public Node getNext()
        {
            return next;
        }

        public void setNext(Node _next)
        {
            next = _next;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: `Node` should be parametrized (with E) when used like here: `private Node head;`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Alright :( [Please read this to understand raw types.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main problem here is that generic `<E>` in Node hides the `E` from `LinkedList<E extends Comparable<E>>`. This warning should appear here:

```
private class Node<E extends Comparable<E>> {
                   ^ here you should get a warning with the message
                   The type parameter E is hiding the type E
}
```

Since `Node` is an inner class, it has direct access to the generic `E` declared in `LinkedList`. This means, you can easily declare `Node` class without the generic type:

```
private class Node {
    E data;
    Node next;
    //rest of code...
}
```

Then you can easily use `Node node` variables inside your class.

---

Note that if you declare `Node` as a static class, then the generic would be necessary and then you should not declare raw variables. This would be:

```
private static Node<E extends Comparable<E>> {
    E data;
    Node<E> next;
    //rest of code...
}

private Node<E> head;
```

Where the `E` used in `static class Node` is different from the `E` generic declared in `LinkedList`.

Answer (score 2):

```
private Node head;
```

This piece of code is throwing the warning.  Node expects to have a type when it is declared. Ex.

```
private Node<something> head;
```

You are not specifying anything so it is warning you that you have not specified a type.

In your case you probably want:

```
private Node<E> head;
```

Comment: *Sigh* I just use the downvote in its right way: *This answer is not useful*. If you think my answer is not useful, just downvote me, I won't get mad :). You're taking this too seriously.